# Catalan interpretation

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, catalan-numbers

I have question and I think the answer is equal with Catalan numbers. The question as follows:

The number of the sequence $a_0a_1a_2\cdots a_na_{n+1}$ of integers with $a_i\geq 2, a_0=a_{n+1}=1$ and $a_i \vert (a_{i-1}+a_{i+1})$, where $1\leq i\leq n$ is equal Catalan numbers.

I obtained some values of these sequences:

For $n=1$ we have $121$,

For $n=2$, we have $1231, 1321$,

For $n=3$, we have $12341, 12531, 13231, 13521, 14321$

For $n=4$, we have
$$123451,123741,125341,125831,127531,132341,132531,135231,135721,138521,143231,143521,147321,154321.$$

I try to define bijection between these sequence and other interoperation of Catalan numbers.

Please let me know if you have any comments to help.
Thanks.

Comment: You mention that $a_i\ge 2$ but in the list for $n=5$, you have included the element $147121$. Can you recheck this and edit? Also, the last list has elements of different lengths. For example, $1432341$ has length $7$ and $145721$ has length $6$.

Comment: @UmeshShankar Thanks. I recheck it.

Comment: As you are looking for an equipotent set, it reminds "Catalan space invaders" https://oeis.org/A000108/a000108b.gif (see more generaly Catalan entry https://oeis.org/A000108 on site OEIS)

Comment: For an improved clarity, I suggest the following re-writing of the second paragraph "Consider; for a given $n$, the set $S_n$ of numbers whose decimal representation $\overline{a_0a_1a_2\cdots a_na_{n+1}}$ is such that $a_i\geq 2, a_0=a_{n+1}=1$ and $a_i \vert (a_{i-1}+a_{i+1})$ for $i=2 \cdots n$. Claim : The number of elements of set $S$ is equal to a Catalan number."

Comment: @JeanMarie are you sure that is the intent? I read it as just a sequence of integers.

Comment: @Joffan: Good observation : indeed, "my" interpretation limits the range of the $a_i$ to be in $[1,9]$.

Comment: This is problem 6.19.(iii) in _Enumerative Combinatorics_ vol 2 by Stanley, part of a list of 66 (!) combinatorial interpretations of the Catalan numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Note that every valid sequence has three consecutive entries $a,c,b$ for which $c=a+b$. Indeed, you can let $c$ be any maximal element of the sequence. Furthermore, when you delete  this $c$ from the sequence, the remaining sequence is still valid. Conversely, you can extend any valid sequence by taking two adjacent terms, $a$ and $b$, and inserting $a+b$ between them. The key observation is that *every* sequence can be built starting from $11$, and repeatedly performing these insertions. It turns out that all of the ways to perform the insertions are exactly described by binary trees.

Here is a bijection between valid sequences and binary trees with $n+1$ leaves. I will illustrate via example with the sequence $132531$. Start with $n+1$ unconnected vertices, which will be the leaves of the tree. The vertices are labeled with the pairs of consecutive entries in the list. Since the list has $n+2$ numbers, there are $n+1$ consecutive pairs.

```
13  32  25  53  31
```

Then, we join up certain pairs of these vertices which are adjacent in left-to-right order, as follows. If $ac$ and $cb$ are adjacent, then they are joined together if and only if $c=a+b$ (we showed earlier that such a pair always exists). The two are joined to a parent node, which is labeled $ab$.

```
  12      23
 /  \    /  \
13  32  25  53  31
```

You then repeat this process, constraining your attention to the set of nodes which do not have parents. So, in the above diagram, we look at $[12,23,31]$, and see that only $23$ and $31$ can be joined together (because $3=2+1$) to a node labeled $21$. This leaves the parent nodes $12$ and $21$, which can be joined to $11$. This is the completed tree:

```
        11
       /  \
      /    \
     /      21
    /      /  \
  12      23   \
 /  \    /  \   \
13  32  25  53  31
```

This mapping from valid sequences to binary trees is a bijection because it has an inverse mapping. Given a binary tree, label the root with $11$, and then for each internal node labeled $ab$, label its left child with $a(a+b)$ and  its right child with $(a+b)b$. The sequence of leaves, read left to right, will be of the form $1a_1,a_1a_2,\dots,a_n1$, and the inverse operation outputs $1a_1a_2\dots a_n1$. Since $11$ is valid, and the insertion operation preserves validity, the resulting sequence is valid.

Comment: Very nice answer (+1).

Comment: @ Mike earnest Thanks. Interesting bijection.